# Guardar Alarmas y dar estilos en Excel mediante vb.net usando Visual Studio

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, vb.net, excel

Estoy programando en vb.net una función que llamaré cada vez que se active, acuse o se inactive una alarma.
Quisiera saber como cambiar el color de la línea introducida en el Excel, o el color de la fuente, para poder diferenciarlas en el Excel.

Como extra también me gustaría meter varios botónes que haga un filtrado por alarmas Activas, inactivas, acusadas, o todas.
La pregunta es como inserto un botón en Excel que ejecute código?
Pues tampoco es que sepa insertar el botón en Excel.
Ando bastante perdido y necesito ayuda.
Si necesitan que especifique algo más por mí encantado.
Un saludo, y que tengan un buen día.
Samuel

```
 Public Sub GuardarAlarmasTXT()
    'Crea un directorio y un txt sino estan creados
    Dim rutaDirectorio = "D:\Virus\Año 2021"
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(rutaDirectorio)
    Dim filename As String = rutaDirectorio + "\Alarmas.csv"
    Try
'Abro el archivo para introducir datos
        Dim file2 As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file2 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filename, True)
    '¿Puedo introducir texto HTML en el Excel o cambiar el estilo de la letra o fondo?  
        Dim descrip = "<strong>la salud</strong>"
    '¿Puedo cambiar la fuente?
        Dim fuenteBody = New Font(Me.Font.Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
        file2.WriteLine(textoAlarma)
        file2.Close()
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("No se han podido escribir valores en el fichero de alarmas")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Si quieren que les pase el código que tengo de prueba puedo hacerlo, pero tiene un poco de paja, la cual saqué para facilitarles la lectura

Comment: No termino de entender tu problema... No estas generando un archivo de excel, estas generando un csv, que es simplemente un archivo con campos separados por coma. Ese archivo, no tiene ni formatos ni nada. Si queres dar formato y otras cosas en excel, deberias abrir un excel y guardar los datos directamente ahi. Y que quiere decir un boton en excel? un boton en donde?

Comment: Vaya tienes toda la razón.... Intento guardar cambios de color en el .csv y no los guarda.... Ahora todo empieza a tener sentido... Vaya muchisimas gracias :D

Comment: Y entonces? cual es la pregunta? porque aca hay simplemente un error de logica...

Comment: mmm, a ver es que realmente este problema de lógica me genera más problemas. Puesto que yo usaba la separación por comas para crear una especie de tabla... xD. Estado, Hora, Descripción de la Alarma... Pero vamos... Cuando prueba a hacer un .xlsx informo por aquí

Comment: ok... esta pregunta la cerramos o la eliminamos o que? porque la respuesta es no se puede